# How to position a ToolStrip under a Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I put the first ToolStrip at the Top of the GroupBox (Documents), then a Panel underneath that (also Dock-Top).
Now I want to put another ToolStrip directly underneath the Panel.
However, none of the positions in the Dock property do this.
As shown, the Dock property is Top, which puts it directly underneath the first ToolStrip and on top of the Panel.

How do I get the 2nd ToolStrip directly underneath the Panel?

[image]

Comment: Use Document Outline Window. (Ctrl + Alt + T)

Comment: It works just fine.  Looks to me you accidentally put the ToolStrip *inside* the panel.  Aim lower.

Comment: @RezaAghaei: I've opened the Document Outline window as you suggested and can see the components listed. What am I to do at this point?

Comment: Drag `ToolStrip` in document outline window and move it up and down drop it in the desired position. It's the most simple solution for moving controls between containers and change order of them.

Comment: @HansPassant: At your suggestion, I played around with where I dropped the 2nd toolbar and I found where it works. As I drag the ToolStrip around the Designer, a thin blue line appears a various positions. This is counterintuitive, but when the thin blue line appears at the bottom of the GroupBox and I drop the ToolStrip there, the ToolStrip then appears at the desired position, underneath the Panel.

Comment: @RezaAgaei: I understand what you are saying now, thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant: If you would combine your suggestions and my follow on, I would accept that as the answer.

Comment: I doubt you need my help to write it up.  Please create your own post and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HansPassant suggested, the trick is to drop the `ToolStrip` in the correct position. What is correct, however, is not obvious.  I played around with where I dropped the 2nd `ToolStrip` and I found where it works. As I drag the `ToolStrip` around the Designer, a thin blue line appears a various positions. When the thin blue line appears at the *bottom* of the `GroupBox` and I drop the `ToolStrip` there and the `ToolStrip` then appears at the desired position, underneath the `Panel`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your second toolStrip inside a regular Panel control which has the `Dock` property set to `Top`

[image]